# Listbox is not resizing in first pass

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 8 listBoxes tagged and represented by _listBox2 and sized at run time.
After reading the number of rows from my database I resize the listboxes with the methods below.

```
        int fonth = _listBox2[0].Font.Height;
        int result = (Nbr_Of_Inscription * fonth) + fonth;
        panel1.Height = result + label27.Height + label14.Height; // this is the panel where lays my listboxes
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
            _listBox2[i].Height = result;
        label27.Top = _listBox2[0].Top + _listBox2[0].Height;
```

And I get this result

[image: 1st display]

When I display a second time without closing the form

[image: 2nd display]

But if I change the line below as this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
            _listBox2[i].Height = result -9;
```

I obtain the second display at first time. That's what I expect to have.

What can be the reason ?
What is that magic number 9?

As info height of font neither the Nbr_Of_Inscription don't change (observed during debug)

My listboxes and my form have the following properties

Comment: You should use a DataGridView control instead.

Comment: I'am lazzy and it works very well (with minus 9). I could change it with Listview but I have to change to much in my codes. I am just curious why this works well with difference of 9

Comment: Without seeing any more code, I would guess it could be a scaling issue.  Try setting this property on your form: `this.AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Inherit;`

Comment: I tried but it gives me the result of first image. Thanks.
They begin to move for closing this topic.
So I will  have the answer on other forum

Comment: I found the reason. The panel where lays the listboxes is invisible before I adjust the height of listboxes . After changing the size of listboxes I was turning it visible state. When I make visible before I change the height of listboxes it works very well. You are right it was in the code somewhere

Comment: Now that is some code I wouldn't want to maintain ever :-)

Answer (score 0):

The panel which holds the listboxes is invisible before adjusting the height of listboxes. 
I make it visible before the changes it works.

```
        panel1.Visible = true;
        int fonth = _listBox2[0].Font.Height;
        int result = (Nbr_Of_Inscription * fonth) + fonth;
        panel1.Height = result + label27.Height+label14.Height;
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
            _listBox2[i].Height = result;
        label27.Top = _listBox2[0].Top + _listBox2[0].Height;
```